# Android studio - Use library from Project in another project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have jar file(use like library) in lib folder in android studio project.

I added another android studio project to the first project.

Added another project steps: File -> New -> Import Module.

I want to use with the file jar from the first project in the another project that I added.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you should add that library again to your new project by following this file -> new -> import module.